# Better way to tabulate some output data in PL/SQL Oracle?

Tags: sql, plsql

Hello I'm practicing PL/SQL by doing multiplication tables, I want each multiplication table to look pretty and I used  CHR(9) to tab each table, however, it only works perfect when the digits on one table and the next one are the same. It looks bad otherwise as you see in the following picture:

[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```
FOR count1 in multiini..multiend LOOP
    FOR count2 in tablini..tablend LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(count2||'x'||count1||'='||count2*count1||CHR(9));
    END LOOP;
    dbms_output.new_line;
END LOOP;
```

Is there a better way to tabulate the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about left padding with spaces, up to maximum result length?

Something like this:

- max result is produced as `multiend * tablend`, so the max length is length of each of them + 2 characters for `+` and `=` + length of the max result itself + 2 spaces more (to look prettier)
- use that length as a parameter of the `LPAD` function

.

```
declare
  multiini number := 2;
  multiend number := 10;
  tablini number := 3;
  tablend number := 20;
  maxlen number := length(multiend) + length(tablend) + 2 + 
                   length(multiend) * length(tablend) + 2;
begin
  FOR count1 in multiini..multiend LOOP
    FOR count2 in tablini..tablend LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(lpad(count2||'x'||count1||'='||count2*count1, maxlen, ' '));
    END LOOP;
    dbms_output.new_line;
  END LOOP;
end;
/
```